# disable bootstrap select option using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I attempt to disable my specific bootstrap select option using javascript.

I know how to disable "normal select option", but when using bootstrap select it just didnt works (its disabled/greyed but i can still choose it)
here [jsfidle](https://jsfiddle.net/ybf5hpam/1/)

```
<select name="dropdownBranch" id="dropdownBranch" class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
  <option value="0">Choose Number</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<select id="pureDropDown">
  <option value="0">Choose Number</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<button onclick="disableDropdown()">disable</button>



function disableDropdown(){
var selectobject;
selectobject=document.getElementById("dropdownBranch").getElementsByTagName("option");
    selectobject[3].disabled=true;

selectobject=document.getElementById("pureDropDown").getElementsByTagName("option");
    for(z=0;z<selectobject.length;z++){
        selectobject[z].disabled=true;
        }

}
```

i try to remove specific option too and the same case happen (work on normal dropdown but not work on bootstrap select)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As described [here](https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select/issues/86), you need to re-render the select picker after changing the disabled property of an option.

This should do the trick: [(JSFiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/ybf5hpam/5/)

```
function disableDropdown(){
    var selectobject;
    selectobject = document.getElementById("dropdownBranch").getElementsByTagName("option");
    selectobject[3].disabled = true;
    $('#dropdownBranch').selectpicker('render');
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is work, but this doesnt apply to tree select using this https://www.patosai.com/projects/tree-multiselect any idea?

Comment: `$('#dropdownBranch').selectpicker('refresh');` is much better for the updated version of bootstrap-selectPicker

Answer (score 2):

use jQuery

`$("#dropdownBranch").attr("disabled", "disabled");`

or the pure javascript one:

```
function disableDropdown(){
    document.getElementById("dropdownBranch").setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ybf5hpam/17/)

Comment: What i want to is to disable specific select option, not disable select (which will disable all select option)

Comment: oh, in that case try to add this code: 

`selectobject=document.getElementById("dropdownBranch").getElementsByTagName("option");

selectobject[3].setAttribute("disabled");`

before you call 

`$('#dropdownBranch').selectpicker();`

Answer (score 2):

Using `render` as mentioned above is no longer the working. As written in their [Docs](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/methods/#selectpickerrefresh) `refresh` is the method to use after changing options.

> To programmatically update a select with JavaScript, first manipulate
>   the select, then use the refresh method to update the UI to match the
>   new state. This is necessary when removing or adding options, or when
>   disabling/enabling a select via JavaScript.

```
function disableDropdown(){
    var selectobject;
    selectobject = document.getElementById("dropdownBranch").getElementsByTagName("option");
    selectobject[3].disabled = true;
    $('#dropdownBranch').selectpicker('refresh');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function disableDropdown(){
  var selectobject;
  selectobject=document.getElementById("dropdownBranch");
  selectobject.options[3].disabled=true;

  selectobject=document.getElementById("pureDropDown").getElementsByTagName("option");
for(z=0;z<selectobject.length;z++){
    selectobject[z].disabled=true;
}
```

}

Comment: it doesnt work, (error on this line i pressume  selectobject.options[3].disabled=true;
)

Answer (score 0):

Yo. Don't you just $.("selectedSelect").css("disabled", "disabled");

Okay. I apologize for my lack of effort. I realize my answer was flippant, and I chose to work on it more. Edit:

This is what I have come across on your jsfiddle. I am getting errors if I use .css, .val, .prop, or .attr. This is making me think that either jquery isn't working properly on jsfiddle for me, or I'm doing something wrong.

I dug deeper. I looked at the html. In jsfiddle, a bootstrap combobox is created above the select tag. I edited the combobox li with the value of 3 to have the class "disabled", and the desired result was obtained.

This led me to this code:

```
function disableDropdown(){
    var selectobject, optionList;
    selectobject=document.getElementById("dropdownBranch")
    .getElementsByTagName("option");
    selectobject = $("li");
    selectobject[3].addClass("disabled");


    selectobject=document.getElementById("pureDropDown")
    .getElementsByTagName("option");
    for(z=0;z<selectobject.length;z++){
        selectobject[z].disabled=true;
    }

}
```

What you need to do is access the bootstrap created element, and modify it to have the class disabled. Bootstrap should take care of the rest. I believe that you can do it in your own environment, but jsfiddle is annoying so I'm not going to continue working on this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fully working "Jquery" version :

```
  var your_value = 2;
  $('#userSelect').val('').change();
  $(`#userSelect option[value='${your_value}']`).prop('disabled', true);
  $('#userSelect').selectpicker('refresh');
```