# How to disable / enable Select in Bootstrap-Select?

Tags: bootstrap-select, bootstrap-selectpicker

I'm trying to disable/enable a `select multiple` dynamically, and I already tried using javascript with disabled, I already tried to use jquery and I already tried to use the methods of the library itself and nothing happens.

```
HTMLElements.forEach(divs => {
                        if(divs.hasAttribute('data-for') && divs.getAttribute('data-for') === 'Contracted Member') {
                            const HTMLInputElements  = divs.querySelectorAll('input'),
                                  HTMLSelectElements = divs.querySelectorAll('select');

                                  HTMLInputElements.forEach(_inputElements  => _inputElements.removeAttribute('disabled'));
                                  HTMLSelectElements.forEach(_selectElement => {
                                      console.log(_selectElement.id)
                                      $('#RSCICMS').prop('disabled', true);
                                      $('#RSCICMS').selectpicker('render');

                                    });

                                  divs.setAttribute('data-status', 'actived');
                        }
                    });
```

**Animation**
[image]

**Note**

> I've tried to follow [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42405672/disable-bootstrap-select-option-using-javascript), but it's no use.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `$('#RSCICMS').selectpicker('refresh')` instead of `$('#RSCICMS').selectpicker('render')`?

From [the docs](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/methods/#selectpickerrefresh): render is only for changing values whereas refresh is used when enabling/disabling the selectpicker.

Comment: This looks like more of a comment than an answer !